# How can I prevent duplication without primary key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `INVOICES` that receives entries from a PHP script. It has many columns, but the two most relevant are `INVOICE_ID` and `INVOICE_TYPE`. Basically the `INVOICE_TYPE` is a number from **0** to **3**, which designates different types of invoices.

Up to this point, everything ran smoothly until two users submitted invoices while the server had a hiccup and wrote both in as the same `INVOICE_ID`. The reason for this is the PHP script reads the MAX `INVOICE_ID` of the `INVOICE_TYPE`, then adds **1**, then inserts the new row with that `INVOICE_ID`. In essence, it is programmatically a `primary key`. **99.9%** of the time it worked, but that one time it was a problem.

I have tried finding SQL solutions but do not have sufficient knowledge of it. I have tried doing it myself in an SQL query to read the MAX, increment, and the insert but just throws an exception that you cannot select and insert from the same table at once.

What I'm wondering is if there is an auto-increment that could be conditional to the `INVOICE_TYPE`, to only increment if the type is matched. Any suggestions would help at this point.

Comment: Not sure I understand - 'MAX INVOICE_ID of the INVOICE_TYPE'  - can you have duplicate invoice ids but they are made unique by being within type? eg 1,1000,2,1000,3,1000,1 2000 (where the first node is type and the second is invoice id).

Comment: @P.Salmon Correct, the INVOICE_ID is made unique by INVOICE_TYPE.

Comment: It sounds like a unique index on type and id would help - is that not a goer? But I don't get why you would structure your data like this is there some relationship between the 3 types with the same invoice id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insert only one row to one table at once simplest solution is to apply unique index on both columns.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX invoice_id_type_unique
ON INVOICES(INVOICE_ID,INVOICE_TYPE);
```

But if you execute more queries based on the same data you need to use transactions to prevent modifying/inserting only part of data.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @invoice_id:=MAX(INVOICE_ID) FROM INVOICES WHERE INVOICE_TYPE=1;
INSERT INTO INVOICES (...,@invoice_id,...);
...
... #OTHER QUERIES UPDATING DATA
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I looked into transaction and seems pretty neat. I also like this because when inserting certain types of invoices I also need to use returned values for the PAYMENTS table.

Answer (score 2):

An unique index over the two columns `(INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_TYPE)` will make one of such hiccupy queries fail.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_type_unique ON INVOICES (INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_TYPE);
INSERT INTO INVOICES (INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_TYPE) VALUES (1, 5);  -- okay
INSERT INTO INVOICES (INVOICE_ID, INVOICE_TYPE) VALUES (1, 5);  -- error
```

Answer (score 0):

make `(INVOICE_ID)` as `UNIQUE`, this will solved your problem, sql will not allowed duplicate value in same column.

Answer (score 0):

The way i like it is to create a table to handle all the sequences and a stored procedure that i can call with the name of the sequence that i like to know the next value, something similar to:

START TRANSACTION;

SELECT value INTO result FROM Sequences WHERE name like paramSeqName FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE Sequences SET value = value + 1 WHERE name like paramSeqName;

COMMIT;

There is a good example here:
http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/emulating-nextval-function-to-get-sequence-in-mysql/